# Replace text with newlines

Tags: java, regex

I'd expect `"A\nC".replaceAll("\\n", "B").replaceAll("B", "\\n")` to return `"A\nC"` but it gives me `"AnC"` instead.

At first I thought the regex escapes may not be recognized in replacements, but `"ABC".replaceAll("B", "\\\\")` does produce `"A\\C"` (that prints as *A\C*).

Can you please help me understand why the \n replacement is not working?

My objective is to replace a given pattern with a newline ("\n") without writing `.replaceAll("...", "\n")` (the replacement string will be given from an external system and cannot contain newlines).

(I tried searching around but found tons of question about replacing newlines with something else and nothing about replacing something with newlines.)

Comment: You yourself found the answer - 4 backslashes are necessary in the replacement pattern to replace with a literal backslash.

Comment: `"A\nC".replaceAll("\\n", "B").replaceAll("B", "\\\\n")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That actually gives the string "A\\nC".

Comment: @Sxilderik: What do you mean to say? See http://ideone.com/nnPHL0, the result is as expected, `A`, a backslash, `C`. If OP needs to get a newline in the results, there is nothing to think of much - `\n` is enough (http://ideone.com/pS8FB7).

Answer (score 1):

You should use "\n" instead of "\\n". "\\n" will compile as "\n", but not as a new line character.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know why you try to escape \n, when it is exactly what you are looking for. This is a line feed char, use it as a normal char, don’t be impressed by the backslash.

```
"A\nC".replaceAll("\n", "B").replaceAll("B", "\n") ==> "A\nC";
```

Comment: Because -as said- the replacement string will be given from an external system and that can't generate newlines characters. Sure, I can solve the problem in other ways, but that's not the point. I'd like to know why I can't use use the escape sequence for newline and if there's a workaround for that.

Comment: This comment seems to be contradictory with the original question. I don’t know what you mean by “use the escape sequence for newline”, as it doesn’t need escaping.

Comment: When I write `.replaceAll("\\n", "B")` I'm using the regex escape sequence for the newline. And that works: `"A\nC".replaceAll("\\n", "B")"` gives "ABC". Why the reverse doesn't?